# I have a question about the output of the fine script variable

Tags: pine-script

I have a question about the output of the fine script variable

When maColor(ma05, ma100) is lime color,

I want to put it in the variable of gold01 and print it out as a plot.

Please help me

```
//@version=5

indicator('Madrid Moving Average Ribbon', shorttitle='Madrid Ribbon', overlay=true)




//Madrid Moving Average Ribbon





// ╔══════════════════════════════════════╗
// ║                                      ║
// ║            CONSTANTS                 ║
// ║                                      ║
// ╚══════════════════════════════════════╝

PHI = (1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2
PI = 104348 / 33215

BULL = 1
BEAR = -1
NONE = 0

// ╔══════════════════════════════════════╗
// ║                                      ║
// ║            Colors                    ║
// ║                                      ║
// ╚══════════════════════════════════════╝


// v3 Style Gradient
GRN01 = #7CFC00
GRN02 = #32CD32
GRN03 = #228B22
GRN04 = #006400
GRN05 = #008000
GRN06 = #093507
RED01 = #FF4500
RED02 = #FF0000
RED03 = #B22222
RED04 = #8B0000
RED05 = #800000
RED06 = #330d06



// ──────────[ v3 Style Colors ]
AQUA = #00FFFF
BLACK = #000000
BLUE = #0000FF
FUCHSIA = #FF00FF
GRAY = #808080
GREEN = #008000
LIME = #00FF00
MAROON = #800000
NAVY = #000080
OLIVE = #808000
ORANGE = #FF7F00
PURPLE = #800080
RUBI = #FF0000
SILVER = #C0C0C0
TEAL = #008080
YELLOW = #FFFF00
WHITE = #FFFFFF



// ╔══════════════════════════════════════╗
// ║                                      ║
// ║            functions ()              ║
// ║                                      ║
// ╚══════════════════════════════════════╝


// ──────────[ Moving Average Color ]
//  
maColor(_ma, _maRef) =>
    diffMA = ta.change(_ma)
    macol = diffMA >= 0 and _ma > _maRef ? LIME : diffMA < 0 and _ma > _maRef ? MAROON : diffMA <= 0 and _ma < _maRef ? RUBI : diffMA >= 0 and _ma < _maRef ? GREEN : GRAY
    macol



// ╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
// ║                                                                              ║
// ║                                main ( )                                      ║
// ║                                                                              ║
// ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝


// ────────────────────[ Input Parameters ]

_10 = input(false, '───────────[ Madrid Ribbon]───────────')
i_exp = input(true, title='Expnential MA')




// ────────────────────[ Processing ]

src = close

ma05 = i_exp ? ta.ema(src, 05) : ta.sma(src, 05)
ma100 = i_exp ? ta.ema(src, 100) : ta.sma(src, 100)



// ────────────────────[ Plot ]
//

gold01 = (maColor(ma05, ma100))== color.new(color.lime, 0))


plot(gold01, color=maColor(ma05, ma100), style=plot.style_line, title='MMA05', linewidth=3)
```

Comment: Your complete code. doesn't compile. Can you update your question with the code which compile (= before you start making modifications) ?

Comment: Yes, I deleted what I answered.
Thank you.
And I can't execute it either because of the wrong code writing..